# How to code a python function that sorts the dates in the list?

Tags: python, string, list, function, datetime

I need a function that sorts the dates in the list. Sorting format should be latest to earliest so biggest dates should appear first as index. What should be inside of function that will work like this?

Here is an example:

```py
date_list = ["22/02/2021", "19/03/2021", "18/01/2022"]

def sorting(date_list):
    pass

sorting(date_list)
# OUTPUT SHOULD BE : ["18/01/2022", "19/03/2021", "22/02/2021"]
```

Comment: This simply boils down to converting these strings into `date` objects, i.e. parsing the date string. Then use that as `key` for `sort`. What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making the string dates actual dates then sort them:

```
def sorting(date_list):
    return sorted(date_list, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y'))
print(sorting(date_list))
```

Or if you want to sort by the day try:

```
def sorting(date_list):
    return sorted(date_list, key=lambda x: int(x[:2]))
print(sorting(date_list))
```

Comment: You’re assuming days will always be double digit?